# 3D map in browser with elevation

Tags: javascript, 3d, maps, webgl

I'm trying to find 3d map js library with support for custom elevation data. I have DTED2 which I would like to load by library.
Second format I have is xyz.
I tried https://openglobus.org/ without success.
Libraries I found so far but had no time to try: cesiumJs and Tangram.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for late response, I think it's better ask in openglobus forum, or github issues. Openglobus supports three terrain providers openglobus, mapbox, and bil16(worldwind). Aslo you can always create your own terrain provider, everything you need to is somehow get terrain tile. Terrain data for openglobus provider is regular grid, and then you just override on of the terrain provider method. For instance take a look inside MapboxTerrain source code and check the example http://openglobus.org/examples/mapboxTerrain/mapboxTerrain.html

Answer (score 1):

[Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-terrain/) renders 3D terrain using x/y/z DEM tiles. [Maplibre GL JS](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/api/) does not render 3D terrain but can be tilted and rotated in 3D.

Edit: [Maplibre supports 3D terrain now](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/3d-terrain/)

Comment: https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/3d-terrain/